# Find int within list and list of list

Tags: python

I am trying to find the min/max number within a list, which also includes a list.

```
list1 = (24,35,18,25)

#Find the min int:
min(83,23,88,[list1])
```

This returns the error:
`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'`

Is there a way of coding this min statement to one line, rather than appending to a new list?

Comment: `min([83, 23, 88] + list1)`.

Comment: Note that your `list1` is a tuple. So to be correct, my statement above should be `min([83, 23, 88] + list(list1))` instead. But you're better off ensuring `list1` is actually a list from the start, instead of a tuple.

Comment: @9769953: Or just concatenate tuples directly as `min((83, 23, 88) + list1)` (probably should rename `list1` though to avoid confusion).

Comment: Given that the OP mentions lists, I assume the intention is that the first variable is a list, not a tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unpack the existing `tuple` with the other arguments:

```
min(83, 23, 88, *list1)
```

That passes the elements of `list1` as if they were additional positional arguments.

Alternatively, build a new iterable and pass it as the sole argument, either by concatenation:

```
min((83, 23, 88) + list1)  # Note: In your code, list1 is actually a tuple, not a list,
                           # so I had to match it with a tuple
```

or via list literal unpacking (new in Python 3.5):

```
min([83, 23, 88, *list1])
```

Only concatenation requires matching types; for unpacking, it doesn't matter what `list1`'s precise type is, as long as it's an iterable.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the lists:

```
list1 = (24,35,18,25)  # Should be named tuple1

new_list = [83, 23, 88] + list(list1)
min(new_list)
```